# How to protest when a moderator deletes an answer?

Tags: support, answers, moderators

Moderators have privileges that other users do not have. It not seem fair to all moderators be from one sect. maybe it is better moderators be from both Shia and Sunni Muslims.

Anyway I do not see any option for appeal when a Question or Answer is completely deleted by an admin.

Comment: Your answer here looks like a comment -- "please add this source, here are some references." Feel free to re-add it as a comment to the main answer which you referred to.

Comment: @ashes999 it was my answer and not a comment. the main answer is deleted and no comment can be added to it. also this question is about how to protest about deletes of moderators and not only about one answer deleted.

Comment: @ashes999, post deletion should be reserved for extreme cases. Deleting posts on meta needs even more extreme situation.

Comment: @Kaveh I commented on his question, and he opened the same question in another meta. I commented that metas should not be duplicated, deleted the dupe, and he opened *the same question again.* The three of us mods agreed that this was the correct action to take in this situation. If you want to discuss it, feel free to pop into chat.

Comment: @ashes999 it was not duplicate. the title of questions were 100% different and 100% different in subject. but text of 2 questions similar (not 100% similar)

Comment: @ashes999, I think that meta question should simply be closed as duplicate in that case. However deletion can be fine if a user starts to spam the meta.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, if you can no longer post on the question or answer itself, you can make a post on meta. One post, not three posts. It helps to post with an open mind and try to understand their reasoning rather than attack their intentions from the outset. Then you can make your case and let them decide whether to keep it closed/deleted or reopen/undelete it.

Comment: I posted 2 and not 3. I posted 3th when 2th was deleted. also there were completely different questions. although similar text of question and I used another question as example. InshaAllah. I hope mods be open mind too.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't saw your answer ,

But in general If you had a bad experience from a moderator , you can ask for help from other moderators via chat and meta posts

If your question is specific to that answer , feel free to ask the separate meta question regarding your answer(ie Why this answer is deleted)

Also moderators represents the community ,not a particular sect . So I don't think sect reservation in moderator-ship is a good idea

Comment: thanks for your guides.

Comment: I posted a question "why this answer is deleted" but it was deleted also!  http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/359/why-this-answer-is-deleted

Answer (score 2):

I have participated in many discussion with the mods, and it seems that none of them are trying to be hostile to other sects. In fact, they are taking the advice of other moderators in many cases. So I don't think an all-Sunni mod set is too bad.

The mods represent the entire site community, not just their own sect. They are free to post answers and comments with their own views, but moderator actions and "official" comments  must be from a neutral point of view.

Comment: OK. but this question is about when a user feels his post is deleted hostile. there is no appeal option like other websites. the problem is near all users here are sunni. I do not have any problem with sunni and consider them brothers/sisters.

Comment: @ahmadi Coming to meta _is_ an appeal. But I feel that you're using the sectarial issue as a [straw man](http://enwp.org/Straw_man) here--the post that I think you refer to had quality issues (not sure, though).

Comment: low quality post should be deleted or downvoted? I feel you are justifying mods.

Comment: @ahmadi we have a specific flag for low quality posts, flags are only for stuff which need a mod to be dealt with. And the only way a mod can deal with these is a convert to comment or a delete. You can still edit to better quality and reflag, the mod may undelete. And there's nothing wrong in justifying the mods, I believe that they have acted neutrally and correctly in this case.

Comment: there is not option for appeal on undelete so I posted on meta. you think it is nutral. but a shia does not have such view. there is nothing more important about 12 in shia view than 12 successors and I posted it as a shia view answer.

Comment: @ahmadi To appeal, you may either flag, or come to meta. Either is fine. I know it was a shia answer, but that's not why it was deleted.

Comment: if your accuse about straw man is true I ask God help me correct myself. but if it is false I ask God forgive you.

Comment: @Ahmadi: Not an accusation. I'm saying that to me it looks like a straw man more than a valid argument. Im not too sure either.